# A beginner who's stuck . 1.In the PHP, in the value of $sql, why did we need the \ symbol (twice)?

Tags: php, mysql

In the PHP, in the value of $sql, why did we need the \ symbol (twice)?

```
//do the SQL
$sql = "UPDATE `starwars`.`Films` SET `Title` = 'Star Wars (aka \"A New Hope\")' WHERE `films`.`Episode` = 4";
$dosql = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: `"UPDATE starwars.Films SET Title = 'Star Wars (aka "` this is a complete string otherwise.  So it's little surprise to me you have to escape them or you'll get a syntax error.  Like unexpected T_STRING  from the PHP compiler deal

`aka "` this ends the string because it matches the first quote.  Without escaping

Comment: Ps. I never got that one before that's how I know it so well.... lol.  Happens all the time without a good IDE>